# MergeSort in 2D Array Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, mergesort

I have function for which should sort 2D String array according to some feature index. Here is my 2D array of 4 elements (4 x 10).

```
String[][] testArr = {
                {"192.168.1.101-67.212.184.66-2156-80-6","192.168.1.101","2156","67.212.184.66","80","6","13/06/2010 06:01:11","2328040","2","0"}
               ,{"192.168.1.101-67.212.184.66-2159-80-6","192.168.1.101","2159","67.212.184.66","80","6","13/06/2010 06:01:11","2328006","2","0"}
               ,{"192.168.2.106-192.168.2.113-3709-139-6","192.168.2.106","3709","192.168.2.113","139","6","13/06/2010 06:01:16","7917","10","9"}
               ,{"192.168.5.122-64.12.90.98-59707-25-6","192.168.5.122","59707","64.12.90.98","25","6","13/06/2010 06:01:25","113992","6","3"}
                };
```

I want to sort these elements according to lets say their 7th index, which is (2328040,2328006,7917,113992) in each element respectively. Here is the function I wrote for it:

```
// ************MERGE SORT***************************
public static void mergeSort(String[][] arr,int featureIndex){
        mergeSort(arr,new String [arr.length][84],0,arr.length-1,featureIndex);

}
// MERGE SORT HELPER FUNCTION
public static void mergeSort(String[][] arr,String [][] temp,int leftStart,int rightEnd,int featureIndex){
        if(leftStart >= rightEnd){
            return;
        }
        int mid = (leftStart + rightEnd)/2;
        mergeSort(arr,temp,leftStart, mid,featureIndex);
        mergeSort(arr,temp,mid + 1, rightEnd,featureIndex);
        mergeHalves(arr,temp,leftStart,rightEnd,featureIndex);
}
// Merge 2 Halves
public static void mergeHalves(String[][] arr,String[][] temp,int leftStart,int rightEnd,int featureIndex){
        int leftEnd = (rightEnd + leftStart)/2;
        int rightStart = leftEnd + 1;
        int size = rightEnd - leftStart + 1;

        int left = leftStart;
        int right = rightStart;
        int index = leftStart;


        while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd){
            if(Double.parseDouble(arr[left][featureIndex]) <= Double.parseDouble(arr[right][featureIndex])){
                temp[index][featureIndex] = arr[left][featureIndex];
                left++;
            }else{
                temp[index][featureIndex] = arr[right][featureIndex];
                right++;
            }
                index++;
        }
        // Copy the arrays
        System.arraycopy(arr, left, temp, index, leftEnd - left + 1);
        System.arraycopy(arr, right, temp, index, rightEnd - right + 1);
        System.arraycopy(temp, leftStart, arr, leftStart, size);

}
```

When I run the program it prints out 7917 7917 7917 113992 respectively in each element. How can I fix this?

Comment: your array lines look like parts a structure. I suggest you create a POJO, then you will have a one dimension array. Then you can use any sort algorithm.

Comment: Using a 2D array is a requirement or you can use another structure?

Comment: Actually i have large csv file,  which has more features than 10 and i put them in an array of 250000 data in it like that, i created this just to test my function. I think it can work, just there might be some index error or smth like that. I looked through for 2 hours but could not find it

Comment: No it is not a requirement, the think is that i have to check different sorting algorithms for my university assignment, and check them with csv files with different sizes. just in merge sort a problem like this came out.Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge function has some problems, you could simplify the function to

```java
public static void mergeHalves(String[][] array,
                               String[][] aux,
                               int start, int middle, 
                               int end, 
                               int index) {

    if (start >= end) return;

    int ls = start, le = middle, rs = middle + 1, re = end, size = end - start + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (rs > re) {
            aux[i] = array[ls++];
        } else if (ls > le) {
            aux[i] = array[rs++];
        } else if (Double.parseDouble(array[ls][index]) 
                <= Double.parseDouble(array[rs][index])) {
            aux[i] = array[ls++];
        } else {
            aux[i] = array[rs++];
        }
    }

    System.arraycopy(aux, 0, array, start, size);

}
```

Using this approach (merge sort of a array of arrays), you would need to deal with the types in the array, because in this case you cannot use parseDouble the columns 0, 1, 3 and 6. You could use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) of string `Comparator<String>` as variable in `mergeHalves()` replacing the comparation in the else if with `comparator.compare(array[ls][index], array[rs][index]) <= 0`. Then defining and passing the comparator acording to the type of data.

Comment: Thank you very much :).You can not imagine how I am very grateful to you. It works in my test file Just in my original file it gives Nullpointer Exception when parsing Double values and comparing them in the method you wrote.Any idea why it can happen?

Comment: NullPointer exception happen when you pass null to parseDouble, you should check that before comparing.

Comment: Thank you yeah i found the error caused because it was comparing with null line.

Answer (score 2):

Put the arrays in an ArrayList instead of the outer array. `Arrays.asList()` can be used for that.

Define a `Comparator` that takes two arrays and sorts them using the 7th element

Use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` to sort it for you. It uses MergeSort.

You can never code anything as good as the standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I really appreciate it. But in my assigment i have to code them myself and make some sorting algorithms compatible with the file.

Comment: I have done this function first to sort some double values in 1D array. But when i converted it so that it can work in 2D array. Problem like that came out. Do u have any idea of the problem?Why the result is like that?